# Can I adjust Workflow Rule to only trigger email alert when formula field value changes not any time its updated to same value?

Tags: workflow, formula-field, opportunity, email-alert

This is My workflow rule

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( Number_c ),
    ISPICKVAL( StageName , 'Closed Won')
)
```

The problem I have - currently I get an Email alert even if the field has the exact same value as before, I want to trigger the email alert only when the Number_c field changes at least by +/- 1
Number_c is a formula field on Opportunity

Comment: I've tested it in my sandbox and I don't receive the email alert if the formula field doesn't change. Can you share the formula in the Number__c field, please?

Comment: IF(ISPICKVAL(Type,"Pilot"),0,MRR__c * 12
)

Answer (score 0):

No, because workflows cannot trigger from a change in a datatype/formula field.

As of January 2021 fields that have the data type = “formula” cannot trigger workflows, and this is a pending idea   https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrIGAA0

Possible workaround:
You could however base your workflow on a non-formula field, and you could even use flow or another tool to calculate/write a value (even formula) into a non-formula-type-field which in turn could trigger workflow. Btw workflows are great for email alerts but as a reminder Do avoid using workflow field updates per the 2021 Architect blog https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/trigger-automation/